# How can I bridge ETH to zkEVM Testnet?

Tags: testnets, polygon, polygon-bridge, zkevm

I want to get some ETH in Polygon zkEVM Testnet network. How can I bridge it and from which network should I do it?

Comment: Do some research in the docs and you will find all the answers.
Here is the bridge https://wallet.polygon.technology/zkEVM-Bridge/bridge

Comment: Thank you but it seems this only works with Mainnet. I need the Testnet feature.

Comment: On the bottom left corner theree's an option for testnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to https://wallet.polygon.technology/zkEVM-Bridge/bridge, connect your wallet and then click on "Try Testnet" on the bottom left corner. You will be able to send ETH from Goerli to Polygon zkEVM Testnet from there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to buy a small amount of Goerli Eth from Layer Zero and then bridge it through the testnet Bridge to zkEVM testnet. https://testnetbridge.com/